# How can I include a form field in my POST if it is not in the current form?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a page that displays a photo the user has uploaded. I have two forms that provide two different actions. The first form, replace_photo_form, is simply a button that the user pushes to replace the photo. The second form, next_page_form, is a field to enter the caption for the photo as well as a button to proceed to the next page. When the user pushes the next_page button, it should save the caption to the DB and continue to the next page.

```
<body>
  <form id="replace_photo_form">
    <input type="text" name="caption" />
    <input type="submit" name="replace_photo" value="Replace Photo" />
  </form>

  <div>
    <p>This is where some other information is located</p>
  </div>

  <form id="next_page_form">
    <input type="submit" name="next_page" value="Next Page" />
  </form>
</body>
```

I want the caption field to appear directly next to the replace_photo button in the page structure so I included it in the replace_photo_form. The problem is that when I push the next_page button, it doesn't save the POST value for the caption input field as I would like. Ideally I would just include the caption field in the next_page_form so I saves the caption as a POST value, but I need it to appear next to the replace photo button.

How can I include a form field in my POST if it is not in the current form?

Answer (score 3):

Merge the two forms into one that spans both submit buttons (it will still include the input of course).

Then, when the form is submitted, you can check which of the values (`next_page` or `replace_photo`) exists in `$_POST`, therefore discovering which button was pressed and what action you need to take.

This technique will work correctly even if Javascript is disabled. If you are willing to relax this restriction, there are dozens of other options (e.g. hooking the `submit` event of a form to copy the value of the text box from another form in a hidden field of the current form).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to add a listener to the field that ties its value to a hidden field in the second form:

```
<form id="replace_photo_form">
    <input type="text" name="caption" 
        onchange="document.getElementById('next_page_form_caption').value = this.value;"/>
    ..
</form

<form id="next_page_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="next_page_form_caption" name="caption"/>
    ..
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `replace_photo_form` submit before `next_page` button clicked, you can simply add an `onclick` to `next_page` button, like this:

`<input type="submit" name="next_page" value="Next Page" onclick="document.getElementById("replace_photo_form").submit();" />`